# My sticky/fixed-to-top navbar stops being sticky when in tablet/phone mode

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fixed

I've made a sticky/fixed-to-top navbar **with Bootstrap**. It's responsive so the nav options turn into a hamburger menu when the screen is below a set size. I've also added JavaScript from a tutorial so that it scrolls nicely.

It is working fine except in tablet/phone mode when the navbar stops being fixed to the top and becomes static instead. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) for the differences/what it should be like. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

I've tried many versions/tutorials, sometimes I get it to be sticky in both situations but without the hamburger menu expanding etc. This is the best I've got it so far basically. Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">Company</a>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-header-->
    <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/#main-nav.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
    <!--/.navbar-->
</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

and the javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
// navigation click actions 
$('.scroll-link').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sectionID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    scrollToID('#' + sectionID, 750);
});
// scroll to top action
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');         
});
// mobile nav toggle
$('#nav-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#main-nav').toggleClass("open");
});
});
 // scroll function
 function scrollToID(id, speed){
var offSet = 50;
var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
var mainNav = $('#main-nav');
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
if (mainNav.hasClass("open")) {
    mainNav.css("height", "1px").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
    mainNav.removeClass("open");
}
  }
if (typeof console === "undefined") {
console = {
    log: function() { }
};
}
```

Sorry if I've explained anything badly. I attempted the navbar about a month ago and then gave up, so hopefully I've not forgotten anything.

Answer (score 0):

Include  **'navbar-fixed-top'** class to the nav tag ie

```
 <nav class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

It will work fine.

Comment: Wow. How on earth did I miss that? :| I thought I'd put fixed!  I must have gotten mixed up from trying so many different nav tutorials! And somehow missed it even when submitting this question. It's so often silly little things. >.>

Thank you! :)